How to annotate a function that accepts a variadic tuple of types and returns their instances?
I have a function that intialize arbitrary types (used for dependency injection),
and I want to be able to do it for arbitrary number of arguments.
i.e
def resolve[T](t: type[T]) -> T: ...


def batch_resolve[*Ts](*deps: type[*Ts]) -> tuple[*Ts]:
    return tuple(resolve(dep) for dep in deps)


class A: ...


class B: ...


a, b = batch_resolve(A, B)
reveal_type(a)  # Unknown
reveal_type(b)  # Unknown

Which doesn't work ofc
PS: I know that SQLAlchemy does something similar though they statically wrote it like this

@overload
def select(
    __ent0: _TCCA[_T0],
    __ent1: _TCCA[_T1],
    __ent2: _TCCA[_T2],
    __ent3: _TCCA[_T3],
    __ent4: _TCCA[_T4],
) -> Select[Tuple[_T0, _T1, _T2, _T3, _T4]]: ...


@overload
def select(
    __ent0: _TCCA[_T0],
    __ent1: _TCCA[_T1],
    __ent2: _TCCA[_T2],
    __ent3: _TCCA[_T3],
    __ent4: _TCCA[_T4],
    __ent5: _TCCA[_T5],
) -> Select[Tuple[_T0, _T1, _T2, _T3, _T4, _T5]]: ...


@overload
def select(
    __ent0: _TCCA[_T0],
    __ent1: _TCCA[_T1],
    __ent2: _TCCA[_T2],
    __ent3: _TCCA[_T3],
    __ent4: _TCCA[_T4],
    __ent5: _TCCA[_T5],
    __ent6: _TCCA[_T6],
) -> Select[Tuple[_T0, _T1, _T2, _T3, _T4, _T5, _T6]]: ...


@overload
def select(
    __ent0: _TCCA[_T0],
    __ent1: _TCCA[_T1],
    __ent2: _TCCA[_T2],
    __ent3: _TCCA[_T3],
    __ent4: _TCCA[_T4],
    __ent5: _TCCA[_T5],
    __ent6: _TCCA[_T6],
    __ent7: _TCCA[_T7],
) -> Select[Tuple[_T0, _T1, _T2, _T3, _T4, _T5, _T6, _T7]]: ...


Related: How to transform or unpack *args types for typing variadics, How to type-hint Python function that takes tuple of type constructors?, Type hint a tuple whose length is the same as *args but different element types and many more.

def resolve[T](t: type[T]) -> T:
    ...

def batch_resolve[T](*deps: type[T]) -> tuple[T,...]:
    return tuple(resolve(dep) for dep in deps)

The type of the attribute in *deps defines the type per item, not as the result tuple object - hope that makes sense. tuple[T,...] is used to denote a tuple of any length, where each argument is of type T. Hope this helps!
Update: Original post was extended to include new classes A and B. Adding these to the solution produces:
def resolve[T](t: type[T]) -> T:
    ...

def batch_resolve[T](*deps: type[T]) -> tuple[T,...]:
    return tuple(resolve(dep) for dep in deps)

class A: ...


class B: ...


a, b = batch_resolve(A, B)
reveal_type(a)  # A | B
reveal_type(b)  # A | B

Noteably this does not distinguish the type A from B in the result.
For this functionality we would need HKTs as discussed here: https://github.com/python/typing/issues/1216

This would cause T to be a union which is not wanted

Just seen, the update, will add an update
